# A 3-adic valuation of $\Bbb Z_2$: Does $\langle3\rangle\cdot\{3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}:x\in\Bbb Z_2\}$ cover $\Bbb Z_2$

Tags: functions, p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

Does $\langle3\rangle\cdot\{3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}:x\in\Bbb Z_2\}$ cover $\Bbb Z_2$?  Does it fail to assign a $\nu_3(x)$ to any values?

Motivation: I've been shown before that there's no obvious 3-adic value (using the term "valuation" loosely) on the 2-adic integers $\Bbb Z_2$.  However on $\Bbb Z$ we can define the function $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$ and instantly see that the leaves of its graph are the multiples of $3$.  Then knowing $2$ is coprime with $3$, we can define $f$ over $\Bbb Z[\frac12]/\langle2\rangle$ knowing the family of sets over which it surjects contains only numbers not divisible by $3$, and then with $\{3^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}\times \{3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}:x\in\Bbb Z[\frac12]/\langle2\rangle\}$ we have our valuation $\nu_3(x)=n$ for any given integer.

I don't see how this would fail to define the same valuation over the entirety of $\Bbb Z_2$:

$f:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$ as $f(x)=3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}$

Then $\{3^n:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ times the set over which it surjects, gives us our 3-adic value over the whole of $\Bbb Z_2$.

Does this cover $\Bbb Z_2$, or does it fail to assign every number a value for any reason?

Comment: Glancing at this, I ask: what is the mapping to $\Bbb R$ that one needs for a valuation?

Comment: @Lubin I might have avoided the word "valuation" as I know it has a special meaning, while I just want something satisfying $3^{\nu_3(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(y)}=3^{\nu_3(xy)}$ that's consistent with the obvious powers of $3$ in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: Let $y \in 2 \mathbb Z_2$, so $y-1 \in \mathbb Z_2^\times$, hence $x:=\frac13 \cdot (y-1) \in \mathbb Z_2^\times$, so $3x+2^{\nu_2(x)}=y$. Since the other inclusion is even more obvious, $\{3x+2^{\nu_2(x)} : x \in \mathbb Z_2 \}$ is a complicated way to write $2 \mathbb Z_2$. Consequently, $3^k \cdot \{3x+2^{\nu_2(x)} : x \in \mathbb Z_2 \} = 2\mathbb Z_2$ for all $k \in \mathbb Z$, in particular these sets for varying $k$ are neither disjoint nor do they cover $\mathbb Z_2$, which I guess would be what you want. The crucial difference to those subrings is that $3$ is a unit in $\mathbb Z_2$.

Comment: To generalise valuations, you might want to look at ring filtrations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filtration_(mathematics). (And granted that in my previous comment, "disjoint" would not be the right thing to look for here anyway I guess; but one reasonable thing one would want is that the intersection of all filtration steps would be $\bigcap S_j = \{0\}$, whereas for your candidates, they're just all the same.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg The Collatz conjecture says $x+2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{v_2(x)-1}\preceq x$ is a filtration $\mathcal F$ of $\Bbb Z_2$ with reducing powers of $3$ and increasing powers of $4$. The conjecture cannot be stated in clearer terms than that. (a little more is needed, i.e. that $\mathcal F/\langle2,3\rangle$ is connected for all 5-rough positive intgers.)  But defining $3^{\nu_3(x)}$ continues to elude me.

Comment: I am certain the sequences $x+(1-2^{-6n})\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}\cdot3^{\nu_3(x)-1}$ are critical in defining the correct topology / valuation / filtration since these are the "level sets" that converge to the inequality. In a sense they are the finest level sets that respect the fibers of the quotient $\langle2,3\rangle$

Comment: I do not know what "a filtration with reducing powers of $3$ and increasing powers of $4$" is supposed to mean, even in a ring where there is a clear reasonable notion of powers of $3$ and $4$. Further, in the specific ring $\mathbb Z_2$, as said I know of no reasonable way to speak of powers of $3$ to begin with. -- In any case, I think my first comment answers this question.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg it's a good answer, it showed me clearly the problem assigning 3 adic values in $\Bbb Z_2$. A filtration with some property increasing is a set of nested subsets in which the property is greater in each subset than in the superset.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg FWFW this uses the filtration language but is essentially the same maths as I have been stuck on for some number of months - perhaps it is more cleary expressed https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3763104/334732